# Bluetooth Problem turn on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I go to Setting-->Bluetooth to open Bluetooth.
But display always shows: `Bluetooth Turned Off` even my button is On.
I use Ubuntu 18.04.

I have tried many solutions: upgrade bluez,... but not working.
[image: 0]

Comment: Please add to your question  `rfkill list` and `lsusb | grep -i blue` also `journalctl | grep -i blue` mutch output please post it on https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I had the same issue, and after searching a little on web, running `systemctl start bluetooth` to turn on bluetooth, start for me! You might need `sudo` or entering your root password

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: doing `systemctl start bluetooth` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Doing `rfkill list` gives me `14: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
`

Comment: `lsusb | grep -i blue` returns nothing,

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. My hardware is Lenovo Ideapad S145 with a Realtek bluetooth and wifi chipset (rtl8822ce). Did you find a solution?

Comment: @yaron160, I did not find any solution but I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and the problem disappeared :)